# Получить данные по JSON в JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

Доброго времени суток. У меня имеется запрос к OpenWeatherMap, ответ получаю в виде JSON что то на подобие этого:

```
{"coord":{"lon":41.43,"lat":52.73},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"пасмурно","icon":"04n"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":2.82,"pressure":1013.44,"humidity":87,"temp_min":2.82,"temp_max":2.82,"sea_level":1033.23,"grnd_level":1013.44},"wind":{"speed":1.7,"deg":176.5},"clouds":
```

Сама проблема заключается в том, что я не могу взять из этого ответа описание к погоде. Т.е. команда variable.weather.description почему то не работает, как с остальными параметрами. Заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос.

Comment: `variable.weather[0].description`

Comment: @Igor Благодарю, это то что я и искал)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ты недокопировал JSON в вопрос.
2. Чтобы распарсить json надо воспользоваться `JSON.parse`.
3. `variable.weather[0].description`

Comment: Да, что недокопировал я знаю, не думал что это важно) Да и JSON.parse я тоже воспользовался, просто в коде это не привел.

Comment: @Omfis, тогда ответ в комментарии Igor.

Comment: Уже воспользовался его подсказкой) Благодарю, господа.